# How to define which overloaded method will be called when passing in a lambda expression?

Tags: java, java-8, overloading

ExecutorService has two overloaded methods

1. `ExecutorService.submit(Callable)`
2. `ExecutorService.submit(Runnable)`

Instance of which class `Runnable` or `Callable` is created when I write the below code.

```
executor.submit(()->System.out.println("Running in : " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
```

If this is an instance of `Runnable`, how do I pass an instance of `Callable` or vice-versa to `ExecutorService` while using lambda expression?

Comment: You have to return a value, instead of printing your string you should return it, and print the result from the thread that calls future.get.

Comment: Another way to distinguish which method you use is to caste. http://ideone.com/LXmdsq

Answer (score 4):

Since your lambda does not return a value, which is what `Callable.call()` requires, it's a `Runnable`.

Comment: Is there any way to prove this programmatically?

Comment: I think the compiler proves it really well, since it won't compile incorrect code. Try to create a `Runnable` that returns a value or a `Callable` that doesn't return a value.

Comment: Is this question really a duplicate? The associated link did not answer my query regarding `Runnable` and `Callable`

Comment: Don't ask me, I didn't close this. But it does seem to be extremely related to your question. Meaning that there's no problem with lambda ambiguity when there's a return value vs. a void method.

Comment: @TejasUnnikrishnan it addresses the answer for your question, you need to return a value. You distinguish which method you are going to use by returning a value. eg. Runnable does not return a value, and Callable returns a value. So `submit(()->"stat")` uses `call`, and `submit(()->System.out.println("stat"));` uses `run`. The other question addresses a bug, where the compiler did know how you specify which method you are overriding. I don't think they're duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

To have a Callable lambda you have to return something.

```
executor.submit(() -> {great_calculation(); return calculated_value;});
```